# How can I tell the browser to load a html file with a Java servlet?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

The idea is that you can add something to a database, which goes from browser -> java code -> JSP -> java code -> database, and you are then redirected to a page containing the information you sent. The servlets are in place but I cannot redirect to the HTML page from a get request.

I have a servlet to PrintWriter().print() the data in a Json object, but that servlet is called from the javascrit within the HTML page. How can I send the HTML page? Should I parse the HTML page and PrintWriter().print() each line? Is there a more proper way of doing this?

Keep in mind that sending HTML straight from JSP is not an option, and I can't change the structure of the system.

edit: Sorry, I typed that in a rush.

As a preface, the system is similar to StackOverflow, whereby you can submit a 'request' which prompts the community to crowd-source learning material.

Right now, the structure of the system is JS/HTML on the browser side, which communicates with a mySQL DB through an API written in Java. The API goes through JSP which communicates with an inner Java API for accessing the DB. The catch is that I must return Json objects from the API. I know that JSP is essentially useless and I could interface the two APIs without JSP, but this is a first year college project so I don't have the choice.

When you submit something to the database using the url /addrequest (or similar), the system puts the text into the database and then redirects you to /request/idnumber. When you access the /request/* URL, another servlet runs. I want this servlet to tell the browser to open my "request_display.html" page. Then the javascript on that page will call another url to get the Json object through the API, and then it will build the page.

I don't know how to tell the browser to open a html page. Should I just parse the html file and then use response.GetWriter().print() to do send the HTML?

Comment: "Sending HTML straight from JSP" is pretty much what JSP was designed to do.

Comment: I don't even understand the structure of your system. AFAICS you have a design problem due to a misunderstanding of servlets and JSP, so please post an example of what you have and what you want to achieve (preferably in code).

Comment: why do you think JSP would be useless?

Comment: I just said that in passing, I'm probably wrong.

Since I can't use JSP to output HTML (I am specifically not allowed to), what use is it in this system? I don't need it to communicate between the outer and inner APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Servlet:

```
response.sendRedirect("pathOf YourHTMLPage");
```

If you are in a JSP page, try using a form or a "a" element. Like this:

```
<form action="nameOfYourServlet"></form>
```

or

```
<a href="nameOfYourServlet"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't really understand what you are looking for but if you want to redirect user to an html page using servlet this can be done using response.sendRedirect("path to html");

It would be nice if you could explain via some code as your English is hard to understand.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I know, it was a suggestion :).

Answer (score -1):

```
response.sendRedirect("redirect.html");
```

Alternative way

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
sc.getRequestDispatcher("/redirect.html").forward(request, response);
```